# How can I sort the summed up number from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the JSON look like below. I'm finding the way to sort the numberOfPoint after I summed up.

```
    { "data": [
     {
        "id": {
            "year": 2015,
            "Name": "A"
        },
        "numberOfPoint": 2
    },
    {
        "id": {
            "year": 2014,
            "Name": "C"
        },
        "numberOfPoint": 2
    },
    {
        "id": {
            "year": 2014,
            "Name": "B"
        },
        "numberOfPoint": 2
    },
    {
        "id": {
            "year": 2014,
            "Name": "B"
        },
        "numberOfPoint": 2
    },
    {
        "id": {
            "year": 2013,
            "Name": "C"
        },
        "numberOfPoint": 2
    }]
}
```

obj is my JSON.

```
var result = {};

obj.data.forEach(function (a) { result[a["id"]["Name"]] = (result[a["id"]["Name"]] || 0) + a["numberOfPoint"]; });
```

result is look like below

```
{
    "A": 2,
    "C": 4,
    "B": 4
}
```

How can I sort this from largest to lowest numberOfPoint? 
I want the result like this.

```
{
    "B": 4,
    "C": 4,
    "A": 2
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't... the properties of an object can't be sorted.. use an array instead like `[{key: 'B', total: 4},{key: 'C', total: 4},{key: 'A', total: 2}]`

Comment: how can I do the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as below :

```
var result={
    "A": 2,
    "C": 4,
    "B": 4,
    "D": 3
}     

var temp = [];
$.each(result, function(key, value) {
    temp.push({v:value, k: key});
});
temp.sort(function(a,b){
   if(a.v < b.v){ return 1}
    if(a.v > b.v){ return -1}
      return 0;
});

$.each(temp, function(index, obj) {
    alert(obj.k + "-" + obj.v);
});
```

**[Here is JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9dxzstew/)**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help.

```
obj.data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.id.Name < b.id.Name;
});

for(var i in obj.data) {
    console.log(obj.data[i].id.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> var obj = { "data":  [
>  {
>     "id": {
>         "year": 2015,
>         "Name": "A"
>     },
>     "numberOfPoint": 2
> },
> {
>     "id": {
>         "year": 2014,
>         "Name": "C"
>     },
>     "numberOfPoint": 2
> },
> {
>     "id": {
>         "year": 2014,
>         "Name": "B"
>     },
>     "numberOfPoint": 2
> },
> {
>     "id": {
>         "year": 2014,
>         "Name": "B"
>     },
>     "numberOfPoint": 2
> },
> {
>     "id": {
>         "year": 2013,
>         "Name": "C"
>     },
>     "numberOfPoint": 2
> }] }
>
>
> var result = {};
>
> obj.data.forEach(function (a) { 
>    result[a["id"]["Name"]] = (result[a["id"]["Name"]] || 0) +   a["numberOfPoint"];
> });
>
> var temp = [];
> $.each(result, function(key, value) {
>   temp.push({v:value, k: key});
> }); temp.sort(function(a,b){    if(a.v < b.v){ return 1}
> if(a.v > b.v){ return -1}
>   return 0; });
>
> $.each(temp, function(index, obj) {
>  alert(obj.k + "-" + obj.v); });
> ```

I hope you like this..if you like then don't forget to vote me..and thanks @Butani Vijay for nice sorting. i have implemented in common...